Railsでsimple_calendarのGemを使用してカレンダーを作成したいが、自動的に反映されるはずのCSSが反映されない。
Railsのsimple_calendarのGemは,stylesheetsディレクトリ配下のapplication.cssに *= require simple_calendar. を追加すれば自動的に反映されるはずですが、反映されません。エラーなどは出ておらず原因不明です。解決策わかる方いらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。
Railsのバージョンは Rails 7.0.8.1 です。
下記が各ファイルのコードになります。
application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>React App</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
  
</head>

<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>

application.css
/* 
 *= require simple_calendar
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

index.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <p>ログインしています。</p>
    <a href="/your_trips" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">予約内容確認</a><br>
    <%= link_to 'ログアウト', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete%>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "Home" %>
    <div id="root"></div>  
  <% else %>
    <p>ログインされていません。</p>
    <a href="<%= new_user_registration_path %>" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">新規登録</a>
    <a href="/users/sign_in" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">ログイン</a>
  <% end %>
  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <h1>予約画面</h1>
      <p>3ヶ月先まで予約することができます。</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-3">
      <%= week_calendar events: @reservations do |date, reservations| %>
        <%= date.day %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>



